# array.map like function in terraform

Tags: terraform

I want to map a list of object in terraform to get a list of single values.

In javascript this would look something like this.

```js
[{a: 1}, {a: 2}].map(item => item.a)
// [1, 2]
```

How can I do this in terraform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
locals {
  items = [for item in [{a: 1}, {a: 2}]: item.a]
}
```

If we output `local.items` we get the following:

```
items = [
  1,
  2,
]
```